# Explosive energy in a container

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering, explosions

What happens when the explosive energy of a grenade or a bomb is contained in a container, if you will, and no energy can be released through the container in the form of heat or sound etc...? Just theoretically asking?

I just want to know what happens when we take a huge explosion or any explosion and shrink it to a finite point. Theoretically, what happens?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean when you say the container is isothermal? I'm having trouble seeing how this is possible when there's an explosion going on.

Comment: i need to know what happens if a shrink an explosion....the net energy of the explosion remaining the same constant ...... to a finite point ? what happens ?

Answer (score 1):

Explosions such as you describe are exothermic reactions, releasing their stored chemical energy in the form of light, heat and the acceleration of the mass making up the outside of the device.  Because energy is conserved, and because your question stipulates that the explosion is surrounded by an adiabatic barrier, the inside of the container would necessarily heat up as a result of the contained explosion.

Note, too, that this is true regardless of the type of explosion; chemical or nuclear.

Answer (score 1):

The final state would be hot, high pressure gases inside, if it is a sealed container.

Examples of gases would be nitrogen and carbon dioxide, but depend upon the explosive material.